# snmptrap - further confusion

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, snmp

I received really useful advice on this post:
[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486653/snmptrap-underlying-config/486661#486661)

I fiddled with it some more and right now I've only got one box to work with. I opened two sessions, one of which I want to view the traffic dump, and the other to try and send a trap locally.

```
abdmin@alarmux:~$ sudo tcpdump -i any udp port snmp
[sudo] password for abdmin: 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes:
```

and

```
snmptrap -v 2c -c public localhost '' 1.3.6.1.4.1.6032.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.6032.1 s "this is just a generic message"
```

Produces no output in the capture. I also tried:

```
 snmptrap -v 2c -c public 192.75.109.26 '' 1.3.6.1.4.1.6032.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.6032.1 s "this is just a generic message"
```

but no luck. However, if I try with snmpget:

```
snmpget -v 3 -u public localhost 1.3.6.1.4.1.3181.10.6.3.65.1.1.5.0
```

Then, despite the bad username, I see traffic:

```
09:37:22.982531 IP localhost.39595 > localhost.snmp:  F=r U="" E= C="" GetRequest(14) 
09:37:22.982764 IP localhost.snmp > localhost.39595:  F= U="" E=_80_00_1f_88_80_21_7d_b5_2c_0b_e4_f6_5b_00_00_00_00 C="" Report(31)  S:snmpUsmMIB.usmMIBObjects.usmStats.usmStatsUnknownEngineIDs.0=4
09:37:22.983208 IP localhost.39595 > localhost.snmp:  F=r U="public" E=_80_00_1f_88_80_21_7d_b5_2c_0b_e4_f6_5b_00_00_00_00 C="" GetRequest(35)  E:3181.10.6.3.65.1.1.5.0
09:37:22.983447 IP localhost.snmp > localhost.39595:  F= U="public" E=_80_00_1f_88_80_21_7d_b5_2c_0b_e4_f6_5b_00_00_00_00 C="" Report(31)  S:snmpUsmMIB.usmMIBObjects.usmStats.usmStatsUnknownUserNames.0=3
```

How to make sense of this?

Comment: `snmpget` defaults to sending traffic to udp/161 (`port snmp`).  `snmptrap` defaults to udp/162 (`port snmp-trap`).  If you want to capture both snmp and snmptrap traffic, you need to sniff on both ports.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! If you want to put your comment into answer form, I'd gladly give you the rep.